# Which of the two conditional probabilities is larger?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have two events at my disposal where the objective is to find out which of the two is more likely to occur. After some manipulation I get:

$$
\Pr\left( A\geq \theta \mid A\leq B \right)
-
\Pr\left( A\geq \theta \mid A> B \right)
$$

where $A$ and $B$ are random variables of some given distributions, and $\theta>0$ is a constant.

Computing these probabilities is not straightforward since we are conditioning on an event rather than a single random variable.

Nevertheless, based on the form of the expression, it is easy to see that the difference is $<0$. However, I get contradicted by my simulation results which indicate that the difference is not necessarily less than zero.

I believe my simulations are in order, leading me to believe that there is instead something wrong in the above reasoning?

Comment: Say the point $(A, B)$ in the plane is uniformly at random chosen from among $\{(1,0), (3,4)\}$, and $\theta=2$. Then $P(A\geq\theta\mid A\leq B)=1$ while $P(A\geq\theta\mid A>B)=0$. So it's not easy at all to see based on the form of the expression that the result is negative, as it's simply not true in general.

Comment: @Arthur Ok, I see. Thank you for the nice counterexample.